# How to find all possible words?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

In a Word Scramble game on the iPhone, the game tells you how many potential words you could have made at the end of each game.

I want to create my own Word Scramble game and also have this feature, but I can't figure out how they calculate it.

They can't possibly go through every combination in the game to find out if it's a word or not, right? It's a 5x5 board with random letters. Words can be up to 11 letters.

Help me out here, I'm stomped.

The game looks kind of like this:

[image]

You use your finger to make words using the letters within a time limit.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: I'm guessing they check against known words. No need to check all permutations for that. Think of it like a [finite state automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth–Morris–Pratt_algorithm)

Comment: Word games often use a [Directed acyclic word graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph).

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer*: I have only seen such a game, not implemented anything like it.

You can do it with some backtracking algorithm, which generates the words and searches them in a dictionary. However, this will be extremely slow for 5x5 board. So what you can do is to search for the amount of words that you can further generate if you have already generated some word. For example, if you have generated `the`, you have to search for the amount of words, starting with `the..`; if that amount is too low (like for "yoe"), then you can stop further searching. In this way you can prune the search tree and achieve your goal. If your dictinary is sorted, then you can achieve complexity of O(log(number_of_words)) by using simple upper and lower bound (binary-search modifications).

Another thing that could help when generating the board and the answers is to make the game more interactive with the user - give him/her some time to see his/her scores, the scores of others, etc. and start a new game after that period (maybe around 10 seconds will be more than enough). In this way, you can precompute almost every possible word on the next board.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution is to use a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) with all the valid words. You can utilize it's structure to efficiently prune the search space.

The rough upper bound on the number of possible combinations, for 5x5 board with words up to 11 letters, is 100,000,000 words. Most of which would not be valid words (like TNPU in the last row of the image). So with proper pruning during your search and fast data structures for your dictionaries, you should be able to do that quite fast on modern smartphones.